# custom color for different ThemeData in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to define a themeData for light theme and another one for dark theme.

but my problem is that I don't know how to define my own custom color for each themeData like badgeColor, CarColor,... 
[image]

I am searching alot and confused how to do that?

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the solution was:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension ColorSchemeExtension on ColorScheme {
  Color get warning => this.brightness == Brightness.light
      ? const Color(0xFF28a745)
      : const Color(0xFF28a745);
}
```

Comment: This helped me. Thanks! This is how one can access the custom color: `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.warning`

Answer (score 2):

In `MaterialApp`, you have `theme`, `darkTheme` and `themeMode` property, make use of them.

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    // provide light theme colors
  ), 
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    // provide dark theme colors
  ), 
  themeMode: ThemeMode.system, // depending on this, either light or dark theme will be used
);
```

Comment: Yes, I know them, my purpose is to define my custom colors,  not primary or accent color.

Comment: Please add more information to your post, probably a screenshot?

Comment: like this link: https://medium.com/@crizantlai/flutter-how-to-extend-themedata-b5b987a95bb5 , but I want to extend this functionality for my different themes